# Partial declarations of 'FontAwesome' must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, maui

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here (still new to this), but I am trying to get the xaml and code to work. I am trying to create small reusable components that can be reused throughout the application, however, I am getting the following error:

> Partial declarations of 'FontAwesome' must not specify different base classes.

Here is the XAML that I am using:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:FontAwesome"
             x:Class="Editor.UI.FontAwesome">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            FontFamily="FontAwesomeSharp"
            Text="{Binding icon}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

Here is the c# that I am using alongside the template:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace Editor.UI;

partial class FontAwesome : ObservableObject {

  [ObservableProperty]
  public string icon = "";

}
```

Do I need to replace `ContentView` in the xaml with something different? If I change the code to extend `ContentView`, the error goes away. So what would I need to change in the xaml to using this with an `ObservableObject`?

Comment: Your `FontAwesome` class inherits from `ObservableObject` in your C# file and it inherits from `ContentView` in your XAML file. That cannot work and is the cause of your problem. You're mixing View and ViewModel code here. What are you trying to do? Essentially, your View cannot inherit from a MVVM base class like `ObservableObject`, because it's already inheriting from `ContentView` and C# only allows single inheritance.

Comment: The code behind should inherit from ContentView.  Your VM is a different class that inherits ObservableObject.  It will help cut down on confusion if you give them different names

Comment: `xmlns:viewmodel` and `xmlns:local` refer to same namespace. That adds confusion (and probably means you are confused about what those namespace lines do). Do you or do you not intend to have a separate viewmodel? In your current code, you don't. Remove `xmlns:viewmodel` OR create a separate namespace for your viewmodels. If you do want a separate viewmodel, name it `FontAwesomeViewModel` or similar. It will be a different class; don't modify your "code behind". If you don't want a separate viewmodel, then inherit from `ContentView`. You won't be able to use `[ObservableProperty]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1

Classes can only use single inheritance in C#. When working with `partial` classes, the declarations must use the same base class.

In your View's code behind you've changed the base class from `ContentView` to `ObservableObject`, presumably so that you can use the MVVM Source Generators (see Problem 2). This is not possible.

If that's not what you've done, then you've tried to declare a partial ViewModel class with the same name as your View, which again isn't possible.

## Problem 2

You cannot use the [MVVM Community Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/overview) inside your View's code behind, it works with Models and ViewModels only (AFAIK).

## Problem 3

Your binding to the `icon` field won't work, because the MVVM Community Toolkit's Source Generator, which you're using by applying the `[ObservableProperty]` attribute, will actually create a property called `Icon` (mind the uppercase letter) which you would need to bind to.

## Problem 4

You've set up [compiled bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0) without a ViewModel and you cannot use that to self-bind directly to a View's code behind (at least I have never gotten it to work properly). You should remove the `x:DataType` or add an actual ViewModel.

## Solution 1

Add ViewModel properly with different name than View (and fix binding):

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:FontAwesomeViewModel"
             x:Class="Editor.UI.FontAwesomeView">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            FontFamily="FontAwesomeSharp"
            Text="{Binding Icon}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**Code behind**

```cs
namespace Editor.UI;

partial class FontAwesomeView : ContentView
{
    public FontAwesomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new FontAwesomeViewModel();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```cs
public partial class FontAwesomeViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string icon;
}
```

## Solution 2

Skip using a ViewModel, inherit from `ContentView` and bind directly to code behind:

**XAML**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Editor.UI"
             x:Name="MyView"
             x:Class="Editor.UI.FontAwesome">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            FontFamily="FontAwesomeSharp"
            Text="{Binding Icon, Source={x:Reference MyView}}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**Code behind**

```cs
namespace Editor.UI;

partial class FontAwesome : ContentView
{
    private string icon;
    public string Icon
    {
        get => icon;
        set
        {
            if(icon.Equals(value)) return;
            icon = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public FontAwesomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```